# Named imports only supported on http(s), but not on file

Tags: cordova, android-webview

I have a cordova app, running in an android webview and I am trying to use named imports as in the following example:

```
import { A } from ./a.js
```

On Webview 74.0.3729.186 it seems to work only, when the webview loads the javascript file containing the import from http, or https.
If the js file is loaded from `file:///android_assets/www/` it fails with the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I can't find any useful information why this would not work.